# Split one record into two mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I want to split the following data into eight records instead of 6.

```
{ "_id" : "Jane Bari", "position" : [ 1 ] }
{ "_id" : "Katie Young", "position" : [ 1 ] }
{ "_id" : "Bill Ugly", "position" : [ 2 ] }
{ "_id" : "George Brown", "position" : [ 2 ] }
{ "_id" : "Mary Bones", "position" : [ 1, 2 ] }
{ "_id" : "Kate Upson", "position" : [ 1, 2 ] }
```

The last two records are an aggregation; I am trying to get all records sorted by `name` and `position`; however, I have to use the `first` group operator to get a single value when grouping; unsure how to separate the bottom two into four results.

Here is my current query:

```
db.records.aggregate(
{$match: {"hand": "L", $or: [{"match.position": 1}, {"match.position": 2}]}},
{$group: {_id: "$playerName", position: { "$addToSet": "$match.position" }}}
).pretty()
```

Comment: what is your expected ouput for those sample documents?

Comment: @Takis Answer posted

Comment: oh ok good that you solved it, i didn't see that you wrote the answer also. you can mark it as solved(press the button), even if you answered it.

Comment: @Takis brilliant, thank you for your help with that friend, I am new here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separating the array into multiple records is using `unwind`.

The updated code is as follows:

```
db.records.aggregate(
{$match: {"hand": "L", $or: [{"match.position": 1}, {"match.position": 2}]}},
{$group: {_id: "$playerName", position: { "$addToSet": "$match.position" }}},
{$unwind: "$position"}
).pretty()
```

This splits the array into multiple records.